# want to edit the checkbox values in edit.php page

Tags: php, checkbox, edit

i want to edit the checkbox values.... i created an edit page in php.but the selected values (entered from entry page) not showing and can't updatae the values......those entered values are not taken to the edit page, however all the other text entered values are taken accordingly.

.......edit page>>

```
<tr>
    <td align='center'>select gots-:</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="withcupon" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='withcupon','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>with cupon
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="withdiscount" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='withdiscount','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>with discount
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="aschannelpartner" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='aschannelpartner','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>as channel partner
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="freepasses" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='freepasses','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>free passes
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="vendorcontacts" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='vendorcontacts','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>vendor contacts
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="p_option[]" value="reatilersaddresses" <?php if(in_array($result->p_option=='reatilersaddresses','')) { ?> checked="checked"
        <?php } ?>>reatilers addresses
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I had to google this but you have your in_array command incorrect it should be if(in_array('withcupon',$result->p_option))....

Comment: Effectively your doing a comparison inside the first parameter of the in_array command and not doing in_array('what your looking for','in the array)

Comment: yap the function takes atleast two parameter......but the mentioned variable i forgot to define in update page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $result->p_option is an array, you should replace:

```
... if(in_array($result->p_option=='freepasses','')) ...
```

for:

```
... if(in_array('freepasses',$result->p_option)) ...
```

(and all the others "if"...)

Comment: but another thing it took the values with comma operater ....i want as an array for showing the selected fields

Comment: you can explode(",",$string)